# How to open new window from parent window, then later close when parent window loads specific page?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

*Note: I can only do this using JavaScript in the IE11 developer's console.*

On my parent window (www.mysite.com/1.html), there's a link on the page that opens a new page in a separate window (www.mysite.com/9.html).

In mysite.com/1.html (*parent?*), I need to click on (or open) that link to mysite.com/9.html (*child?*) as a separate window. 
Then from the parent window, I need to go to mysite.com/2.html. 
Then, in the same parent window, I need to go to mysite.com/3.html.

Now, when my parent window reaches mysite.com/3.html, I need to somehow close the child window (or close all windows that are not the parent).

How can I do this by calling a function in the parent window?

I'm aware that variables are reset/destroyed when a new page is loaded in a window. But is there a way I can take advantage of cookies to my parent window remember: "oh yeah! I opened *9.html* a while back. I even gave/assigned it a name! Time to close it."

Comment: [Please include the code that you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: in my thinking the browser shouldn't let you do that - it would be a design/security flaw when any page could close any other page.

Answer (score 1):

Open your windows through javascript so that you are able to call window.close() on them. Look at this example http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_close2

```
<script>
var myWindow;

function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", "_blank", "width=500, height=500");
}

function closeWin() {
    myWindow.close();
}
</script>
```

To close the child when the parent is refreshed, add this code in your script

```
function closeIt()
{
  myWindow.close();
}
window.onbeforeunload = closeIt;
```

Comment: This is a close example of the problem I'm experiencing! When I trigger openWin(), the window opens fine, and closes fine with closeWin() too. But when I trigger openWin(), then refresh the parent window, closeWin() no longer works even though the variable 'myWindow' still exists on the reloaded page and hasn't changed. Can I do something to make closeWin() still work?

Comment: use parameters in your url that you read via javascript OR use cookies

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I can use cookies?
I've tried storing the variable `myWindow` using `document.cookie = "myWindow=" + myWindow;` then grabbing the variable from the refreshed page and saving it as a variable by the same name (`myWindow = getCookie("myWindow");`) but that still didn't make the parent window recognize the child window that it had opened earlier on.

Comment: I added code to my answer to close the child windows when parent is refreshed

Comment: That works great! Thanks! But is there a way to close the child window by triggering a function on the new, refreshed parent page?

Comment: maybe you can look into changing the myWindow.opener to the new page after refresh but this is a bug that doesn't work in every browser and I don't think it should be that way.